# Remove extra ticks when tickmarkPlacement: 'on'

Tags: highcharts

I have to use `tickmarkPlacement: 'on'` instead of `between` but I don't need the extra ticks on left and right. My chart should look like a square. Here is the expected result:

[image: The wanted result]

Let's see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gcLGS/

Comment: I can't tell the difference between provided fiddle and the image of expected result. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Look at the extra "lines" in the fiddle: `0 ----|-----` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tickPixelInterval paramter and startOnTick / endOnTick as true.

http://jsfiddle.net/gcLGS/1/

```
xAxis: {
    tickLength: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tickPixelInterval: 100,
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick:true,
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',

},
```

Comment: Well It could be better as my current chart but: 1. you commented `categories` object and I need it. 2. I would like that the chart starts on the first line of the square, not the second. Thank's btw.

Comment: You can use label formatter to return name of categories.